# Creating a custom calendar with appointments from UWA

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, uwp, windows-10

I am using this snippet to create a Calendar and put it in the user's native Outlook Calendar app:

```
async private Task CreateCalenderEntry()
    {
        // 1. get access to appointmentstore 
        var appointmentStore = await AppointmentManager.RequestStoreAsync(AppointmentStoreAccessType.AppCalendarsReadWrite);

        // 2. get calendar 
        var appCustomApptCalendar = await appointmentStore.CreateAppointmentCalendarAsync("MyCalendar1");

        // 3. create new Appointment 
        var appo = new Appointment();

        // appointment properties 
        appo.AllDay = true;
        appo.Subject = "Sample Subject";
        appo.StartTime = DateTime.Now;

        //  4. add 
        await appCustomApptCalendar.SaveAppointmentAsync(appo);
    }
```

The problem is when I invoke this code it creates a new section of calendars in Outlook Calendar with a calendar named "MyCalendar1" within, but what I want is to create it inside the user account's calendar. What I can see is that

```
CreateAppointmentCalendarAsync
```

actually has 1 overload which is

```
public IAsyncOperation<AppointmentCalendar> CreateAppointmentCalendarAsync(System.String name, System.String userDataAccountId);
```

I think this is what I am looking for to address user's calendar, but having in mind that this "userDataAccountId" parameter is the user's id, where should I find it?

Comment: You need a Special capability to add an appointment to User's Calendar. But if you use this capability, App will fail Certification. Please see documentation about this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#device-capabilities). Look for **System Level Appointment Access**

Comment: What is the difference between "System Level Appointment Access" and "User Data Accounts Provider"? The first says that "No one may request access to this capability for store submission." and the UDAP says "Anyone may request access to this capability for store submission."? After all my company and I need to publish this app to the store (and also have good reasons to ask for these capabilities, so I don't think this will be a problem)

Answer (score 1):

> but what I want is to create it inside the user account's calendar

I'm not sure what you actually want to create.If you want to create a new calendar into one existing mail account, by testing on my side, it is not allowed currently. If you want to create new appointments into an existing calendar which belongs to a mail account, you need to specific a restricted capability to your app as @AVK Naidu said. [This picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bv9Y3.png) can better explained what I said.

For how to add new appointments into an exsiting calendar, you can use code as follows:

```
IReadOnlyList<AppointmentCalendar> appointmentCalendars = await appointmentStore.FindAppointmentCalendarsAsync();
foreach (AppointmentCalendar calendar in appointmentCalendars)
{
   if(calendar.DisplayName=="Calendar")
    {
        AppointmentCalendar appointmentcalendar = await appointmentStore.GetAppointmentCalendarAsync(calendar.LocalId);
        await appointmentcalendar.SaveAppointmentAsync(appointment);
    }
}
```

And details for how to set the [appointmentsSystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#special-and-restricted-capabilities) capability is as follows:

```
<Package  
...
xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities" 
IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">
...
<Capabilities> 
  <Capability Name="internetClient" /> 
  <uap:Capability Name="appointments" />
  <uap:Capability Name="contacts" /> 
  <rescap:Capability Name="appointmentsSystem"/>
</Capabilities>  
</Package>
```

Pay attention that with this capability you need to request access to a restricted capability before submitting your app to the store.

> I think this is what I am looking for to address user's calendar, but having in mind that this "userDataAccountId" parameter is the user's id, where should I find it?

[`userDataAccoundId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.appointments.appointmentcalendar.userdataaccountid.aspx) can got from a known [AppointmentCalendar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.appointments.appointmentcalendar.aspx). That's true you can identifier of the user account data by this property. But even you got this property from the calendar which belongs to one user account, it is not allowed to create a new calendar for that user account. You only can use this property to add new calendar to current account. Code as follows:

```
  var appCustomApptCalendarone  = await appointmentStore.CreateAppointmentCalendarAsync("currentacount-one");
  var userdataaccountid  = appCustomApptCalendarone.UserDataAccountId;
  var appCustomApptCalendartwo = await appointmentStore.CreateAppointmentCalendarAsync("currentacount-two", userdataaccountid);
```

More details please reference the [official sample.](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Appointments)

Comment: What is the difference between "System Level Appointment Access"  and "User Data Accounts Provider"?

Comment: In my opinion the previous one is for *appointment* , the last one is for  *mail, calendar, and contact accounts*. Actually all give a system level privilege. Maybe you can try the last one perhaps it work. By the way, if my reply helped y you ,could you please mark as accepted or vote up?Thanks.

Comment: That's all good but I cannot find information about how to use these capabilities to do what I already described anywhere. Is there any sample or anything? I just want to put some Calendars with appointments within inside the users email account Calendar group

Comment: @nmrlqa4. These capabilities are setting in package.appxmainfest, press F7, and you will see the code, update the code like what showed in the answer.

Comment: No, I added them to the manifest, but now how to add a Calendar to the user's account calendar group? Any example?